# "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path" in VB.net

Tags: visual-studio

There are 25 machines on domain and I need to read a file that is protected, I can change manually in each machine which user can read/write but that seems not an option, so I want to know if before the "system.unauthorizedAccessException" appears I can give some credentials like if I were an Authorized user.

This code works only in one machine just because I change manually the folder's security properties so EVERYONE can read/write, but I can't do that in the rest.

```vb
        Do

            If day_dif >= 0 Then
                sum_iteraciones = sum_iteraciones + iteraciones(patho)
                num = num + 1
                patho = "\\" & Eqp & "\Log_SG2X\" & Strings.Right("000" & Year(today), 4) & "\" & Strings.Right("00" & Month(today), 2) & "\" & Strings.Right("00" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Day(today), 2) & "\Sequence\" & Mesa & "\" & Strings.Right("000" & Year(today), 4) & Strings.Right("00" & Month(today), 2) & Strings.Right("00" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Day(today), 2) & Strings.Right("00" & num, 2) & ".log"

                If Not File.Exists(patho) Then

                    num = 0
                    today = today.AddDays(1)
                    day_dif = day_dif - 1
                End If

            End If
        Loop Until today >= day_fin


        Label1.Text = sum_iteraciones
End Sub

 Private Function iteraciones(path As String)
        
        Dim texto As String = File.ReadAllText(path)
        Dim count As Integer = Split(texto, "Probe down.").Length - 1
            Return count
      
    End Function
```